# Drupal 8 Custom module - how to create a field in the admin area, and then pull that input in my module to use?

Tags: drupal-modules, drupal-8

New to Drupal 8, I'm coming from the WP world so it's been very confusing getting the hang of things. I created a custom module and have a page outputting text. Where I'm stuck is the ability to make a field in the admin area, pull that saved info, and then use it in my content that's being output.

Been following along with tutorial but am very stuck. Can anyone provide a road map for me or helpful articles to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose your module name is "**custom**" then follow these steps to create a admin form and pull the saved info on admin page.

Create a folder name "**custom**".

Create "**custom.info.yml**" file within "custom" folder.

```
name: custom
description: Show admin saved data through custom module.
type: module
# core: 8.x
configure: admin/config/services/custom
```

Create a Permission for who access admin form.
For Permission create "**custom.permissions.yml**" file within "custom" folder.

```
'administer custom':
  'title': 'Administer Customform'
  'description': 'Configure how Custom Form is used on the site.'
  restrict access: true
```

Then create a route for custom admin form path & it's content.

Create "**custom.routing.yml**" file within "custom" folder.

```
custom.config:
  path: '/admin/config/custom/config'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\custom\Form\CustomConfigForm'
    _title: 'Custom Configuration'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer custom'
```

Now create a menu and assign this route ("custom.config") in menu path & create a form within custom folder and the form location is
src/Form/CustomConfigForm.php

For menu create a "**custom.links.menu.yml**" file within "custom" folder.

```
custom.config:
  title: 'Custom '
  description: 'Custom Admin Configuration'
  parent: system.admin_config
  route_name: custom.config
  weight: 100
```

For admin form create **CustomConfigForm.php** file within custom folder and the file location is **src/Form/CustomConfigForm.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\ConfigFormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class CustomConfigForm extends ConfigFormBase {

    public function getFormId() {
        return 'custom_config_form';
    }


    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $config = $this->config('custom.settings');  // store data in custom.settings


    $form = parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);

    $form['custom_types'] = array(
      '#type' => 'checkboxes',
      '#title' => t('Content Types'),
      '#description' => t('Configure where the custom button should appear.'),
      '#options' => node_type_get_names(),
      '#default_value' => $config->get('custom_types', array()),
    );

    return $form;
  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $config = $this->config('custom.settings');
    $config->set('custom_types', $form_state->getValue('custom_types')); 
    $config->save(); // save data in custom.settings

    return parent::submitForm($form, $form_state);

  }

  public function getEditableConfigNames() {
    return ['custom.settings'];
  }

}
```

Now when you save admin form then after you fetch the saved data in "custom.module" file to use this code.

Create **"custom.module"** file within custom folder.

```
$config =  \Drupal::config('custom.settings');  // get saved settings
$types = $config->get('custom_types', array()); // fetch particular saved data "custom_types"
print $types;
```

Now enable this module.
Your admin form path is **YOUR_SITE_NAME/admin/config/custom/config**

Also in Drupal 8 sometimes cache problem occurs, so if any problem comes then clear the cache after form save.

Comment: Thank you so much. Very concise and easy to follow. Right now this is popping up in my error log when I try to access the page. My custom module is called google-calendar or in the namespace google_calendar.


InvalidArgumentException: Class "\Drupal\google_calendar\Form\GoogleCalendarConfigForm" does not exist. in Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ClassResolver->getInstanceFromDefinition() (line 24 of /home/vagrant/Sites/gordon/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DependencyInjection/ClassResolver.php).


The config form is definitely there in the Form directory.

Comment: And maybe addtl info will help. My custom module directory is google-calendar, and in the namespace for my controller it's Drupal\google_calendar\Controller.

Comment: Check  your "google-calender.routing.yml" file _form:   path and the namespace used in the GoogleCalenderConfigForm

Comment: I saw the modulename/Form/ and figured that's where the Form directory should go - it actually goes in /src/. As soon as I did that, everything worked just fine. Thank you Ujjval Jha.